# How to take text which is inside ul element not in li element of js

Tags: javascript

while I am taking inner text of ul element inner text of li and a tag also comes so how can I take exact inner text of ul element element only when I target it only.

my code:-

```
   <ul id="a3">
       hey
       <li id="a4">1 points again</li>
       <li id="a5">You have no points</li>
        <li id="a6"><a id="a7" href="cookie_catch.html">points review.<a>
        </li>
   </ul>

 <script>
   var el =  document.getElementById('a3'); 
   console.log(el.textContent)
 <script>
```

How can I take innerText of ul only

Comment: `console.log(el.childNodes[0].data.trim());`

Comment: There should not be any text as a child, only li elements should be children of ul's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the first child node of your element before looking up its text content, using `.childNodes[..]` :

```js
var el = document.getElementById('a3');
console.log(el.childNodes[0].textContent)
```

```html
<ul id="a3">
  hey
  <li id="a4">1 points again</li>
  <li id="a5">You have no points</li>
  <li id="a6"><a id="a7" href="cookie_catch.html">points review.<a></li>
</ul>
```